# What is this manga of a girl running a boarding house for aliens?

Tags: safe-again-today

I can't remember the name of a manga series that featured a human girl running a boarding house for aliens as they adjust to human lives. The aliens wore human bodies, and there was one male alien in a woman's body.

I believe the protagonist had black hair that was short or tied back. I think it came out in late 1990s-early 2000s.

It was slice of life, seinen, I think.

Comment: Is it [*UFO Baby*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_Baby)?

Comment: No, the drawing style wasn't cutesy at all. I think the girl had short black hair.

Comment: Could it be [Narue no Sekai](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=4910)?

Comment: No, the MC wasn't it high school as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it finally. It's a Korean Manhwa called [Safe Again Today](http://myanimelist.net/manga/5399/Safe_Again_Today).

[image: image from MAL]

**Synopsis:**

> Choi Sera houses displaced aliens in her home, where they all pretend to be UFO fanatics in order to explain their eccentricities. Sera's job is to teach these aliens how to live in human society—not that difficult on the surface, as they ostensibly look like humans (except for the three fingers on each hand thing). They look normal, and they can communicate with earthlings via a translator that looks like a hearing aid, but can they act normal? The answer to that is a resounding no. Watch as Sera tries to school the emotionless twins, Seunghyun and Seungmin (really clones) on dating (with disasterous results), tries to keep Hyunwoo out of trouble, and keep them all from being taken away by the UN alien hunter who's on to them.